# How to make an event handler fire only once in JQuery for the Selectors with multiple items?

Tags: jquery

I have following JQUERY code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".voteup").click(function(){
        alert($(this).parents(".webresource").attr("id"));
    });
</script>
```

The page has 4 elements with classname voteup. But when I click on one of them, alert is displayed four times. I would think that there is only one click so the event handler function would execute only once.

What do I do to ensure that the event handler function is executed only once.

Comment: is that script created dynamically? i dont see that issue when i make a fiddle out of it

Comment: Ditto, works fine in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F6bSM/

Comment: Are you including that script in your page 4 times?  Also, you should wrap that in a document ready handler, to ensure that the DOM is ready to be manipulated when it executes.

Answer (score 4):

[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) binds an event handler and the unbinds it on its first execution.

```
$('.upvote').one('click', function() {
   ...
});
```

Also, I'd make sure it's not being bound multiple times somehow as Ender suggests in your comments.

Comment: thank you for this excellent tip, this will make my work a lot easier!